# Change raster panel titles using levelplot

Tags: r, raster, levelplot, rastervis

I'm using RasterVis and levelplot to make a trellis plot of some rasters. I am currently ok for most things but I would like to change the header for each panel from the filename to a chosen string (the filename is convoluted and long, i want to use just a year, for example '2004').

Looking at the [levelplot page](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/lattice/levelplot), it would indicate that levelplot goes looking for some settings as per the argument 'useRaster', either it goes to [panel.levelplot or panel.levelplot.raster](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/panel.levelplot.html), but im struggling to use these latter functions.

Any help much appreciated, here's some sample code;

```
require(rasterVis)

layers <- c(1:4)
s2 <- stack()

for (i in layers) {
  r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100,ext)
  r[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE)
  rasc <- ratify(r)
  rat <- levels(rasc)[[1]]
  rat$legend <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
  levels(rasc) <- rat
  s2 <- stack(s2, rasc)
}

levelplot(s2, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(6)),main = "example")
```

In the above e.g., I would like "layer.1.1" to be "2004", and so on through to 2007

Comment: `names` argument of `levelplot`. What is `ext` object?

Comment: @ Pascal, sorry that was a raster extent i missed off the top of the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
require(rasterVis)

layers <- c(1:4)
s2 <- stack()

for (i in layers) {
  r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
  r[] <- sample(seq(from = 1, to = 6, by = 1), size = 10000, replace = TRUE)
  rasc <- ratify(r)
  rat <- levels(rasc)[[1]]
  rat$legend <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
  levels(rasc) <- rat
  s2 <- stack(s2, rasc)
}
levelplot(s2, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(6)),main = "example", names.attr=2004:2007)
```

[image]

```
p.strip <- list(cex=1.5, lines=1, col="blue", fontfamily='Serif')

levelplot(s2, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(6)), main = "example",
          names.attr=2004:2007, par.strip.text=p.strip)
```

[image]

Comment: is that it? just the names argument? but where is it on the help? can you adjust the font etc as well?

Comment: @Sam I wrote `names`, but strictly should be `names.attr`. In help page: *Character, names to use in each panel. If missing its default value is the result of names(x) (after subsetting the layers to be displayed).*